# Java calling a subclass from a class using a different java file and class

Tags: java, class, methods, call, subclass

I have this main java file:

```
public class GroceryBill {
    private Employee clerk;
    private List<Item> receipt;
    private double total;
    private double internalDiscount;

    public GroceryBill(Employee clerk) {
        this.clerk = clerk;
        receipt = new ArrayList<Item>();
        total = 0.0;
        internalDiscount = 0.0;
    }

    public void add(Item i) {
        receipt.add(i);
        total += i.getPrice();
        internalDiscount += i.getDiscount();
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return Math.rint(total * 100) / 100.0;
    }

    public Employee getClerk() {
        return clerk;
    }

    public void printReceipt() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    private String valueToString(double value) {
        value = Math.rint(value * 100) / 100.0;
        String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
        if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
            result += "0";
        }
        result = "$" + result;
        return result;
    }

    public String receiptToString() {
        String build = "items:\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < receipt.size(); i++) {
            build += "   " + receipt.get(i);
            if(i != receipt.size() - 1) {
                build += "\n";
            }
        }
        return build;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total);
    }

    public String discountToString() {
        return receiptToString() + "\nsub-total: " + valueToString(total) + "\ndiscount: " + valueToString(internalDiscount) + "\ntotal: " + valueToString(total - internalDiscount);
    }

    public static class Employee {
        private String name;

        public Employee(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private String name;
        private double price;
        private double discount;

        public Item(String name, double price, double discount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.discount = discount;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public double getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }

        private String valueToString(double value) {
            String result = "" + Math.abs(value);
            if(result.indexOf(".") == result.length() - 2) {
                result += "0";
            }
            result = "$" + result;
            return result;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + valueToString(price) + " (-" + valueToString(discount) + ")";
        }
    }

//  REPLACEME

}
```

I want to call and be able to use getDiscount() and etc from the "Item" subclass, but I can't figure out how to access it in a different file + class that extends GroceryBill.

```
public class DiscountBill extends GroceryBill {
    
    private int myCount;
    private double myDiscount;
    private double myPrice;
    private String myName;
    
    public DiscountBill(Employee clerk, boolean preferred) {
        super(clerk);
        String name = "";
        double price = 0;
        double discount = 0;
        GroceryBill.Item myBill = new GroceryBill.Item(name, price, discount);
        Object myItem = new Item(name, price, discount);
        myDiscount = myBill.getDiscount();
        myPrice = ((GroceryBill.Item) myItem).getPrice();
        if (preferred && myDiscount > 0.0) {
            myCount++;
        }
    }
    
    public int getDiscountCount() {
        return myCount;
    }
    
    public double getDiscountAmount() {
        return myDiscount;
    }
    
    public double getDiscountPercent() {
        return (myPrice / getDiscountCount()) * 100;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my class that is in a different java file that extends the original one. How would I call methods from the Item subclass that belongs to the GroceryBill class?

Comment: `Object myItem = new Item(name, price, discount);` looks suspicious. The actual question is not clear at all, what are you trying to achieve and where (NB: putting each class in it's own file might help you)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

Create object to super class using that object try to create object for its sub class.

for example:

```
public class Sample {
class InnerClass
{
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Helolo");
    }
}
}
```

Base class is :

```
public class BaseClass extends Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample sObj = new Sample();
    Sample.InnerClass innerObj = sObj.new InnerClass();
    innerObj.foo();
}
}
```

You can follow this approach to call inner class methods

To access inner static classes :

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

In your case just add statement like :

```
GroceryBill.Item = new GroceryBill.Item(name, price, discount);
```

Comment: I implemented this, but it gives me a "qualified new of static class" error which I'm trying to debug.

Comment: Do you really need the static modifier for you inner class coz if you remove that static modifier, you can access it without any trouble.

Comment: Yea, I see it's the "static" modifier of the class "Item", but the given superclass cannot be changed and that includes taking out the static.